Simulate typing effect in BATCH
i'm trying to simulate a typing effect in BATCH, and this is what i originally had:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "word=example"
set "output="
for /l %%x in (0, 1, 6) do (
    set "output=!output!!word:~%%x,1!"
    cls
    echo !output!_
    ping localhost -n 1 -w 200 >nul
)
cls
echo !output!
pause

however, this doesn't work and instead just echoes the word entirely without simulating any typing effect. any solution?
tried: the code above
expected: a simple, clear typing effect in which it types out the word.
result: just echoed the word, and no typing effect was actually simulated.

I wonder if this fails because you're using the ping command to simulate a delay. try commenting out cls and remove > nul to get more debug information.

The code you posted works fine, it just looks like it's displaying everything all at once because a) the argument for -w is given in milliseconds and the minimum valid value for that is 500, and b) -w is the timeout but since you're pinging localhost it will never fail so the command has no reason to wait.

@SomethingDark i've switched the command out for ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul and it's pretty slow for what i need, is there a command that can delay faster than 500 ms?

That's as fast as you're going to get in native batch. If you need something lower than that, I'd recommend taking the old school approach of having a for /L loop that does nothing a bunch of times, but the time it takes to finish is going to vary wildly by the speed of the CPU that it's running on.

See this search results for several good answers, utilizing other (built-in) languages to overcome the "minimum time barrier".

Does this help at all?
It uses the built-in PATHPING.EXE utility, (instead of PING.EXE), to allow for a shorter delay between typed characters, in 'native batch'.
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "STRING=This may contain possibly problematic characters, ^?&|*=%%<>)!""
(For /F %%G In ('"Prompt $H& For %%H In (1) Do Rem"') Do For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /U /E /D /C "Set /P "^=!STRING!" 0<NUL" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ""') Do Set /P "=.%%G%%I" 0<NUL & %SystemRoot%\System32\PATHPING.EXE 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 100 1>NUL) & Echo(
Pause

Just run it, as is, to see it working, then feel free to change the content of STRING as needed. You can also adjust the 100 in the PATHPING arguments to see how that affects the 'typing speed'.

yup, this works really well. thanks!

The use of a while loop and some simple maths to track centiseconds elapsed can be used to implement delays of the appropriate duration for this type of output.
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CLS

(Set \n=^^^

%= do not modify this multiline \n definition =%)

rem @wait macro by T3RRY - wait approximately n centiseconds
rem usage: %@wait% n
rem usage: %@wait% "equation"

Set @wait=For %%. in (1 2)Do if %%.==2 (%\n%
  Set "$wait.do=1"%\n%
  For /l %%^^~ in (1 1 16)Do if defined $wait.do For /l %%^^~ in (1 1 16)Do if defined $wait.do For /l %%^^~ in (1 1 16)Do if defined $wait.do For /l %%^^~ in (1 1 16)Do if defined $wait.do (%\n%
    For /f "tokens=1,* Delims= " %%i in ("$waitamount ^!@wait.args:* =^!")Do If not "^!%%i.CS^!"=="^!time:~-1^!" (%\n%
      Set /A "@wait.Target=%%~j","@wait.tDiff=^!time:~-1^!-%%i.CS","%%i.CS=^!time:~-1^!"%\n%
      If "^!@wait.tDiff:~0,-1^!"=="-" (%\n%
        Set /A "@wait.tDiff+=10,%%i.elapsed=%%i.elapsed %% 100000000+@wait.tDiff"%\n%
      )Else Set /A "%%i.elapsed=%%i.elapsed %% 100000000+@wait.tDiff"%\n%
      If ^^!%%i.elapsed^^! GEQ ^^!@wait.TARGET^^! (%\n%
        Set /a "@wait.tDiff=0,%%i.elapsed=0"%\n%
        Set "$wait.do="%\n%
      )%\n%
    )%\n%
  )%\n%
) Else Set @wait.Args=

rem @strlen macro - port of strlen function by Jeb. rem returns the length of a string.
rem usage: %@strlen% sourceVar returnVar
rem https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1429&start=15#p6267

Set @strlen=For %%. in (1 2)Do if %%.==2 (%\n%
  For /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("^!@strlen.Args^!")Do (%\n%
    Set "@strlen.t=^!%%~i^!"%\n%
    If defined @strlen.t (%\n%
      Set "%%j=1"%\n%
      For %%P in ( 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 )Do (%\n%
        If not "^!@strlen.t:~%%P,1^!" == "" (%\n%
          Set /a "%%~j+=%%P"%\n%
          Set "@strlen.t=^!@strlen.t:~%%P^!"%\n%
        )%\n%
      )%\n%
    )Else set "%%~j=0"%\n%
  )%\n%
) Else Set @strlen.Args=

rem vt sequence used to facilitate output of whitespace and = character via set /p.
rem vt sequences require windows 10 build 10589 or newer.

for /F %%a in ('Echo(prompt $E^| %comspec%')Do Set \E=%%a

Set "string=hello world^!"

%@strlen% string $len

For /l %%i in (0 1 !$len!)do (
  <nul set /p "=%\E%#5!string:~%%i,1!"
  %@wait% "!random! %% 8 + (!random! %% 6 + 6)"
)
echo(
Pause
Endlocal & goto:eof

For information on macro's with arguments, see: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1827
For information on Virtual terminal sequences, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
